# Post-hoc test of two-way permutation ANOVA

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, two-way, permutation

I have a 2x2 study design to test the interaction between two drugs, with a single variable outcome. The data are very much non-parametric and it seems that a good alternative to the traditional two-way ANOVA is to use a permutation ANOVA, e.g. `aovp(outcome ~ drugA * drugB)` from the `lmperm` package.

My question is what is the most appropriate way to run a post-hoc test on the resulting `aovp` object, to make adjusted comparisons between specific drug combinations? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: The only way I know to do this would be to use pairwise comparisons of treatments.  That is, if *drugA* is significant, compare, e.g. *A1* to *A2*, *A1* to *A3*, and *A2* to *A3*.  Each with a permutation test.  I don't particularly like doing this kind of pairwise comparison because each comparison ignores all the rest of the data that's not in that comparison.

Answer (score 0):

***Answer from comments***:

> The only way I know to do this would be to use pairwise comparisons of
> treatments. That is, if *drugA* is significant, compare, e.g. *A1* to *A2*,
> *A1* to *A3*, and *A2* to *A3*. Each with a permutation test. I don't
> particularly like doing this kind of pairwise comparison because each
> comparison ignores all the rest of the data that's not in that
> comparison.