# After permutation ANOVA, is it appropriate to use bootstrapping for posthoc analysis?

Tags: nonparametric, permutation-test

A [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/553060/post-hoc-test-of-two-way-permutation-anova) indicates that after conducting a permutation ANOVA and finding a significant interaction, permutation tests would be suitable for pairwise comparisons.

However, I also saw online tutorials (e.g. this [blog post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/08/bootstrapping-follow-up-contrasts-for-within-subject-anovas-part-2/), or an [older one](https://shouldbewriting.netlify.app/posts/2019-05-09-bootstraping-rm-contrasts/) from the same author) presenting how to use bootstrapping to obtain contrasts, confidence intervals and p-values after conducting a permutation ANOVA.

How should I decide which is the suitable approach?